# Associate on create?

Tags: laravel

A user has many posts. A post belongs to one user.

The relationship on the post model is:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

But when I want to use `create` and also associate a user, I get a call to undefined method error...

```
$user = \App\Models\User::find(10);

$post = Post::create($request->validated());

$post->associate($user);
```

How can I use `create` and then `associate` a user?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the `user()` method before calling `associate()`.

```php
$user = \App\Models\User::find(10);

$post = Post::create($request->validated());
$post->user()->associate($user);
$post->save();
```

Or even better, associate the user before saving the post so only one query is executed:

```php
$user = \App\Models\User::find(10);

$post = new Post($request->validated());
$post->user()->associate($user);
$post->save();
```

Comment: The questions asks - "How can I use create and then associate a user?"

Comment: "your code should gives you an error unless you did something wrong" - error mentioned in original question.

Comment: Still doesn't work, your first section under "You forgot to call the user() method before calling associate()." fails to associate.